# Dot product vectorization - NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a function which I would like to vectorize away the remaining loop.  I believe it is correct and I am happy with performance, but would just like to know more about vectorizing code.  The function is:

```
def f(x, A, c):
    # A : d*d numpy array
    # c : length d numpy array
    # x : N x d or length d numpy array
    x = np.atleast_2d(x)
    b = np.zeros(x.shape[0], dtype=np.bool)
    for row in range(x.shape[0]):
        xmc = x[row, :] - c
        b[row] = xmc.dot(A).dot(xmc) <= 1
    return b
```

Is it possible to vectorize the function and remove the remaining loop while keeping it reasonably simple?  Are there any guidelines for when independent calculations in a loop cannot be vectorized well?  Typical values for N and d are 10000 and 4 respectively.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could vectorize like so -

```
xc = x-c
b_out = ((xc.dot(A))*xc).sum(1) <= 1
```

You can also use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
xc = x-c
b_out = np.einsum('ij,jk,ik->i',xc,A,xc) <= 1
```

Runtime tests -

Define functions:

```
def org_app(x, A, c):
    x = np.atleast_2d(x)
    b = np.zeros(x.shape[0], dtype=np.bool)
    for row in range(x.shape[0]):
        xmc = x[row, :] - c
        b[row] = xmc.dot(A).dot(xmc) <= 1
    return b

def vectorized_app1(x,A,c):    
    xc = x-c
    return ((xc.dot(A))*xc).sum(1) <= 1

def vectorized_app2(x,A,c):    
    xc = x-c
    return np.einsum('ij,jk,ik->i',xc,A,xc) <= 1
```

Timings:

```
In [266]: N = 20
     ...: d = 20
     ...: A = np.random.rand(d,d)
     ...: c = np.random.rand(d)
     ...: x = np.random.rand(N,d)
     ...: 

In [267]: %timeit org_app(x,A,c)
1000 loops, best of 3: 274 µs per loop

In [268]: %timeit vectorized_app1(x,A,c)
10000 loops, best of 3: 46 µs per loop

In [269]: %timeit vectorized_app2(x,A,c)
10000 loops, best of 3: 63.7 µs per loop

In [270]: N = 100
     ...: d = 100
     ...: A = np.random.rand(d,d)
     ...: c = np.random.rand(d)
     ...: x = np.random.rand(N,d)
     ...: 

In [271]: %timeit org_app(x,A,c)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.74 ms per loop

In [272]: %timeit vectorized_app1(x,A,c)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 ms per loop

In [273]: %timeit vectorized_app2(x,A,c)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.72 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me a vectorized version.  However your version is ~5x slower on my machine.  I guess vectorized isn't always faster.  Also, can I just assume that independent calculations in a loop can almost always be vectorized, although sometimes it won't help performance?

Comment: @user2133814 Sorry, check out the edit please, must be much faster now.

Comment: Perfect.  I like the first one.  I might be able to do similar on my own in the future.  einsum looks pretty neat, but probably needs some getting used to.  Thanks

Comment: the timing differences get even more dramatic when N >> d, which is my use case

Comment: @user2133814 Dramatic in favour of the vectorized approaches I hope! Aren't they?

Comment: correct, vectorized being ~100x faster, I think because the loop is over a longer span but the work done at each loop iteration is relatively smaller

Comment: @user2133814 Exactly! Well, that's why one must look to *kill* loops! :)